Getting "@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function" error after migrating Kotlin 2.0
I got this strange error after migrating my project to Kotlin 2.0.
@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function
My project level build.grandle.kts
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.4.1" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "2.0.0" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization") version "1.9.21" apply true
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.compose") version "2.0.0" apply false

}

tasks.register<Delete>("clean") {
    delete(rootProject.layout.buildDirectory)
}

App level build.grandle.kts;
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "2.0.0-1.0.21"//"1.9.22-1.0.16"
    id("kotlinx-serialization")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.compose") apply true
}

android {
    compileSdk = 34
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.test"
        minSdk = 33
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
        ndk {
            //noinspection ChromeOsAbiSupport
            abiFilters.addAll(listOf("arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a"))
        }
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        named("debug") {
            applicationIdSuffix = ".debug"
        }
        named("release") {
            applicationIdSuffix = ".release"
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            isShrinkResources = true
            proguardFiles(
                    getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                    "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlin {
        compilerOptions {
            jvmTarget.set(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.JvmTarget.JVM_1_8)
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
        viewBinding = false
        buildConfig = true
    }
    
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes.add("/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}")
        }
        jniLibs {
            useLegacyPackaging = false
        }
    }
    namespace = "com.test"
}

dependencies {
    api(fileTree(mapOf("dir" to "libs", "include" to listOf("*.jar", "*.so", "*.aar"))))
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.13.1")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.8.1")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.9.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.4.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.5.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:21.2.0")
    implementation("androidx.security:security-crypto-ktx:1.1.0-alpha06")
    implementation("androidx.leanback:leanback:1.0.0")
    implementation("androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.3.7")
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.13.1")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    testImplementation("com.google.truth:truth:1.4.2")

    // Jetpack compose
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.05.00"))
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    implementation("androidx.compose.foundation:foundation")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.compose.ui:ui-util:1.6.11")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.7")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.8.1")
    implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata")
    implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-rxjava2")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.1")

}

settings.grandle.kts;
import org.gradle.api.initialization.resolve.RepositoriesMode

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven {
            url = uri("https://jitpack.io")
        }
    }
}

pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google {
            content {
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.android.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.google.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("androidx.*")
            }
        }
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "Test"
include(":test")

What is the issue here? I clean the project, invalidate caches but it doesn't seem to be working.

where is the error in your code, you posted your gradle and that has nothing to do with the error

It is also I don't understand .There is no visible error on Android Studio or anywhere else, when I try to build I got this error.

We need to see the code where this error occurs. Please [edit] your question and add the compose function where the compiler raises the error.

If you don't see any errors in Android Studio and have tried cleaning the project and invalidating the caches, then try deleting the .gradle folder, followed by syncing and rebuilding the project.

I am having the same issue.
